# GCP - apache-beam.io.textio.ReadFromText gives SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-shell

I was trying to run an apache-beam pipeline on Google cloud platform using Cloud Dataflow. However It doesn't seem to go past this line of code :

```
p | 'GetFile' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input_filename)
```

It returns this warning and stays stuck:

**WARNING:root:Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 5.14973849643 seconds before retrying exists because we caught exception: SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)**

Here is my code:

```
import apache_beam as beam

PROJECT='xxxx'
BUCKET='xxxx'

class Split(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        IATA,AIRPORT,CITY,STATE,COUNTRY,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE= element.split(",")
        return [{
            'IATA': IATA,
            'AIRPORT': AIRPORT,
            'CITY': CITY
        }]

def run():
    argv = [
      '--project={0}'.format(PROJECT),
      '--job_name=examplejob2',
      '--save_main_session',
      '--staging_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
      '--temp_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
      '--runner=DataflowRunner'
   ]
    p = beam.Pipeline(argv=argv)
    input_filename = 'gs://{0}/airports.csv'.format(BUCKET)
    output_filename = 'gs://{0}/output.txt'.format(BUCKET)



   # find all lines that contain the searchTerm
    (p
      |'GetFile' >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText(input_filename) 
      |'Split' >> beam.ParDo(Split()) 
      |'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(output_filename)
   )


    p.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Can someone please help solve this issue ?

Comment: In `input_filename = 'gs://{0}/airports.csv'` you are missing to replace the bucket name with `.format(BUCKET)`. Is this just a typo?

Comment: Did a quick test with a dummy file and it worked for me (2.16.0 SDK)

Comment: @GuillemXercavins i just forgot to copy paste the line but in my console I did replace the bucket name and still gives me that error, I'll edit that line in my post.